# Redirect user to another screen

Tags: javascript, java, spring, model-view-controller, jspx

I'm developing a website using javascript, jspx, and java (Spring using Mvc). I have an admin profile where I can shut down sessions from another logged users, my problem is that when I log out those users they stay in the page they were, and they are redirected to the log-in page when they click in another link, so, they are not aware that they were log out after they try to move to another page in the website. Is there a way that I can redirect them immediately after I shut them down?

PD: To shut their session down I'm using sessionRegistryImpl.

```
    sessionRegistryImpl.getSessionInformation("userId").expireNow();
```

Thank you!

Comment: You need to do poling from javascript to server or notify browser by web socket from server to reload page when session expires.

Comment: Maybe [this article](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/) can shed some light on the problem you are trying to solve, although it offers examples only in PHP and nodeJs.

Answer (score 1):

You could try and use `HttpServletRequest request` and `HttpServletResponse response`, after you expire the session use the response method to redirect

```
response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/login");
```